# Where does pIOContextForward member set to not NULL value?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, iocp

I am trying to use this [Windows IOCP sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/winsock/iocp/server) as a starting point in my own IOCP server development.
There is a structure `_PER_IO_CONTEXT` in `IocpServer.h`.

```cpp
//
// data to be associated for every I/O operation on a socket
//
typedef struct _PER_IO_CONTEXT {
    WSAOVERLAPPED               Overlapped;
    char                        Buffer[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    WSABUF                      wsabuf;
    int                         nTotalBytes;
    int                         nSentBytes;
    IO_OPERATION                IOOperation;
    SOCKET                      SocketAccept; 

    struct _PER_IO_CONTEXT      *pIOContextForward;
} PER_IO_CONTEXT, *PPER_IO_CONTEXT;
```

It's used in another structure `_PER_SOCKET_CONTEXT`.

```cpp
//
// data to be associated with every socket added to the IOCP
//
typedef struct _PER_SOCKET_CONTEXT {
    SOCKET                      Socket;

    LPFN_ACCEPTEX               fnAcceptEx;

    //
    //linked list for all outstanding i/o on the socket
    //
    PPER_IO_CONTEXT             pIOContext;  
    struct _PER_SOCKET_CONTEXT  *pCtxtBack; 
    struct _PER_SOCKET_CONTEXT  *pCtxtForward;
} PER_SOCKET_CONTEXT, *PPER_SOCKET_CONTEXT;
```

From comments we can guess that `pIOContext` could be used as linked list, `pIOContextForward` member serves for this purpose.
And it is even used during resources cleanup in `IocpServer.Cpp`:

```cpp
//
// Free all i/o context structures per socket
//
pTempIO = (PPER_IO_CONTEXT)(lpPerSocketContext->pIOContext);
do {
    pNextIO = (PPER_IO_CONTEXT)(pTempIO->pIOContextForward);
    if( pTempIO ) {

        //
        //The overlapped structure is safe to free when only the posted i/o has
        //completed. Here we only need to test those posted but not yet received 
        //by PQCS in the shutdown process.
        //
        if( g_bEndServer )
            while( !HasOverlappedIoCompleted((LPOVERLAPPED)pTempIO) ) Sleep(0);
        xfree(pTempIO);
        pTempIO = NULL;
    }
    pTempIO = pNextIO;
} while( pNextIO );
```

But `pIOContextForward` member is never set to anything except `NULL`.
May be `pIOContextForward` implicitly set during operations on overlapped structures?
May be this member was assumed to be used, but code is not complete?
I want to understand how this code will handle multiple asynchronous tasks on one socket and it seams that `pIOContextForward` should be used to implement such functionality.

So my question is how `pIOContextForward` member is assigned with it's corresponding value?
And if this code is not complete, how can I elaborate it?

Comment: `pIOContext` should be set to something other than `NULL` [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/67a8cddc25880ebc64018e833f0bf51589fd4521/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/winsock/iocp/server/IocpServer.Cpp#L212). Otherwise [this code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/67a8cddc25880ebc64018e833f0bf51589fd4521/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/winsock/iocp/server/IocpServer.Cpp#L228) a few lines below would segfault.

Comment: i think examples is bad. we not need store pointers to `PER_IO_CONTEXT` at all. we pass pointer to `PER_IO_CONTEXT` to I/O call. and if I/O not fail - got it back when I/O complete. not need store this.